# QGIS and SQLite wrongly changing layer type on import

Tags: qgis, spatialite, sqlite

I have been struggling for a few days now with importing Linestring
layers into Spatialite.

Every time I save the layers into a sqlite file, they are automatically
converted to MultiLinestring, even though they are perfectly normal
Linestring files in all other formats I tested (SHP and TAB).

Has anybody come across this before? Is this a bug?  Or am I doing it wrong?

Comment: Have you checked the source shapefile so that it does not contain any multilinestring features?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using the QSpatialite plugin, I indeed noticed that importing a SHP file into a Spatialite DB creates a Multilinestring table. Instead, use the DB Manager plugin and select *Create single-part geometries instead of multi-part*. That should do it.

[image]